# Как запретить скачивание файлов с сервера?

Tags: django, nginx

Всем привет, подскажите как правильно скрыть файлы от скачивания. К примеру у меня есть видео, которое доступно только группе пользователей, но если кто-то скинет ссылку на это видео, то запретить его скачивать и смотреть, как это правильно реализовать?
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую именно сторону смотреть, спасибо.

Я смотрел запрет через nginx, но я так понимаю что он станет недоступным даже для отображения на самом сайте

```
location ^~ /files/score/ {
deny all;
return 404;
}
```

Comment: Делать раздачу файлов не через nginx, а через Django, и уже внутри Django выполнять все нужные проверки доступа https://wellfire.co/learn/nginx-django-x-accel-redirects/

Comment: Можно сделать через Nginx, но чтобы доступ контролировало приложение. Это делается через [X-Accel-Redirect](https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nginx_x_accel.txt.html)